# Is there a single-jar Java REST server implementation?

Tags: java, rest, executable-jar

I want to make a simple REST service that initiates multicasting of a file based on a get request. I really need it to be as lightweight as possible in terms of resources.

Preferably I'd like to have it as a standalone executable jar. Is there such a solution out there?

The simplest I've found so far are RESTX and RestExpress, but they don't appear to be single-jar solutions.

Comment: There's always the option to repackage an existing solution as single jar using tools like ProGuard

Comment: Isn't Jetty just a single JAR?

Comment: I can't answer this question because it's closed, but a solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802335/endpoint-publish-for-rest-web-services/21330224#21330224